# Numeric Format BEST15.2 allows how many places after decimal in SAS

Tags: format, sas

I am confused to see SAS Numeric Format BEST15.2 is allowing more than two palces after decimal. What is the correct interpretation of BEST15.2

Comment: Can you give any examples of the code, values and output that you have?

Answer (score 2):

Looking up the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fum54c93f8r0n1wrs5mrb05nzi.htm) the Best format only has a width specification, not a decimal specification.

Further, the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fum54c93f8r0n1wrs5mrb05nzi.htm) does say:

> Numbers with decimals are written with as many digits to the left and
>   right of the decimal point as needed or as allowed by the width.

which might explain what you are seeing.

An alternative could be the [BESTDw.p](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0wi1eyjui7p3fn1g7912tl3lqyg.htm) format which allows you to specify the decimal precision:

> Prints numeric values, lining up decimal places for values of similar
>   magnitude, and prints integers without decimals.

Comment: Thanks Amir for the response I was too thinking the same as doc says that the right of the decimal should be at max less than equal to left. So that is why it allows such values.

Comment: This is the point of the `BESTw.d` format: it adjusts the decimal based on the number.  `w.d` is correct if you want to keep the decimal consistent (or `Fw.d`).